# Path to assets in Symfony2 assetic tool

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I have a problem to reference my css files in directory

```
src\FirstLast\Bundle\AppBundle\Resources\public\css
```

using assetic command?
I should use something like:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/firstlastapp/css/*' filter="cssrewrite" %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

but this doesn't work.
That one works, but as expected cssrewrite fails:

```
@FirstLastAppBundle/Resources/public/css/*
```

Any cues?

A solution given by VisioN:

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink should do the job.
```

Comment: `php app/console assets:install web --symlink` should do the job.

Comment: That's really nice. I was confused that "@Acme..." works, while "bunble/acme..." doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> but this doesn't work

What happens exactly ?

Assuming you're in prod mode, you should launch the command `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod`. It will export your different files once and for all and not each time the page is rendered like in dev mode.